# Не срабатывает отмена одного из множественных курсоров

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Не срабатывает отмена одного из множественных курсоров. При клике на один из множественных курсоров, для удаления, сбрасываются все курсоры, вместо одного необходимого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо с нажатым `Alt` **выделить** область в которой находятся неверно отмеченные курсоры.

P.S. Отмена последнего курсора `Ctrl+U`

Comment: Выделение одного из множественных курсоров с зажатой клавишей `Alt` отрабатывает.  `Ctrl+U` не отрабатывает.

Comment: Alexandr, Emmet имеет, ПМСМ, отвратительное свойство — перекрывать горячие клавиши по умолчанию, почему у людей не работает сочетание `Ctrl+U` и не только. Добавили бы в ответ, что если стоит Emmet, нужно в `Preferences` → `Key Bindings - User` добавить строку `{ "keys": ["ctrl+u"], "command": "soft_undo" },`, и шорткат `Ctrl+U` будет функционировать. Спасибо.